# Normalization by min-max & stand deviation method to only certain columns using Python or R

Tags: python, r, normalization

I have a dataframe which has 37 variables and 50,000 rows. There are both categorical and numerical features. I would like to do the normalization function to some columns in the dataframe.

Here is a fake dataset:

```
diagnosis   gender  area    age weight    score   compactness   class
 447          1     95.88   50  117.66      674.8      80         0
 167          0     109.3   65  118.8       886.3      35.6       2
 444          0     117.5   80  160.85      990        64.2       2
 100          0     88.05   35  94.98       582.7      35.23      1
 227          1     97.45   40  15.51       684.5      70         1
```

I want to do normalization only to area, weight, score, compactness for example. How should I do it? BTW, I found a stand deviation method from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-use-statistics-to-identify-outliers-in-data/) , but it meant for normalizing the whole dataset and the code is:

```
# identify outliers with standard deviation
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std

# calculate summary statistics
data_mean, data_std = mean(data), std(data)
# identify outliers
cut_off = data_std * 3
lower, upper = data_mean - cut_off, data_mean + cut_off
# identify outliers
outliers = [x for x in data if x < lower or x > upper]
print('Identified outliers: %d' % len(outliers))
# remove outliers
outliers_removed = [x for x in data if x >= lower and x <= upper]
print('Non-outlier observations: %d' % len(outliers_removed))
```

My question is how can do normalization only to some columns in a dataframe? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: in `base` `R`, you can make a vector with the names of the columns you want to use (`v=c("weight","score" ...)`) and then apply the functions only to those columns using `dataset[,v]=apply(dataset[,v],2, function(x){ ... }`

Comment: If it is just about the selection of variables, then you can use `df[, grep("area|age|weight|score", names(df))]`.

Comment: @boski  would you bother to give me more details? I tried with this using R, then I got lost  m<-mean(data$age)
s<-sd(data$age)
cut_off = s * 3
lower=m-cut_off
upper=m+cut_off
outliners<-ifelse(, outliners) Note: I even did not try yet to put all of them into vector

Comment: @tmfmnk Can you give me more hints ? tks

Comment: `grep()` looks for the given variables in column names of df. For matching columns, it returns their column index and then it subsets the df based on this column index.

Comment: @tmfmnk tks! is it so,  after I selected the data columns, using that grep function like you mentioned : data[, grep("area|age|weight|score", names(data))], just infront of this line # calculate summary statistics
data_mean, data_std = mean(data), std(data), then i should get the result, right?

Comment: Well, the selection of variables should be made before the calculation of statistics. If this is your question.

Comment: @tmfmnk, thanks I will try it

Answer (score 0):

I actually have a written function for automatic normalization that I use. It is the following:

```
n <-function(x){
  d=dim(x)
  c=colMeans(x)
  xm=sapply(1:d[2],function(i){
    x[,i]=x[,i]-c[i]
  })
  # xm is the x with removed means
  v=var(xm) # variance matrix
  xn=sapply(1:d[2],function(i){
    xm[,i]=xm[,i]/sqrt(v[i,i])
  })
  xn
}
```

Then just apply this function to the desired columns.

```
tochange=c("age","weight","score")
df[,tochange]=n(df[,tochange])
> df
     diagnosis gender   area        age     weight      score
[1,]       447      1  95.88 -0.2161373  0.3000106 -0.5282662
[2,]       167      0 109.30  0.5943775  0.3212536  0.7290858
[3,]       444      0 117.50  1.4048924  1.1048216  1.3455747
[4,]       100      0  88.05 -1.0266521 -0.1226130 -1.0757939
[5,]       227      1  97.45 -0.7564805 -1.6034728 -0.4706004
     compactness class
[1,]       80.00     0
[2,]       35.60     2
[3,]       64.20     2
[4,]       35.23     1
[5,]       70.00     1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!